# How to display ordered list inline in tweeter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists

I am using `Twitter bootstrap` 3.3.1,

```
    <ol class="list-inline">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
      <li>Integer molestie lorem at massa</li>
      <li>Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet</li>
      <li>Nulla volutpat aliquam velit</li>
      <li>Faucibus porta lacus fringilla vel</li>
      <li>Aenean sit amet erat nunc</li>
      <li>Eget porttitor lorem</li>
    </ol>
```

But it is not displaying in a line and list numbers are also not showing, please help me to just display the ordered list inline

Comment: do you have bootstrap css and bootstrap js attached to your page?

Comment: please, post the entire html code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css code in your css file. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists) the default bootstrap css style for list.

```
ol.list-inline > li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsyt84x6/2/)

```
<ol class="list-inline">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `<ul>` is for unordered lists.

Answer (score 0):

still working fine, check the example:

Here: [jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/Lsyt84x6/1/)

```
<ul class="list-inline">
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Phasellus iaculis</li>
      <li>Nulla volutpat</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<ol class="list-inline">
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Phasellus iaculis</li>
      <li>Nulla volutpat</li>
</ol>
```